# How do I connect my javascript code to QR Code generator API?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm a beginner in javascript and developing a QR generator for my school project. I wanted to ask for a solution on connecting the QR code generator API that I've used in my code, I've tried to type "&{data}" in the QR Code API URL but it didn't work. the result that I was expecting is that the text that I've entered in the textarea will convert into a QR Code.

Here is the code of my work:

```js
let qrcode = select("img");
let qrtext = select("textarea");
let qrbtn = select("button");

qrbtn.addEventListener("click", generateQR);

function generateQR() {

   
    let data = qrtext.value;
    let baseURL = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=1000x1000&data=&{data}";

    

    qrcode.src = baseURL;
}


function select(el) {
    return document.querySelector(el);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use a template literal? (Uses backticks, not quotes, and variables are surrounded by `${}`) Try `\`..url/?&data=${data}\``

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!!!